# Output Queue of a Python multiprocessing is providing more results than expected

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

From the following code I would expect that the length of the resulting list were the same as the one of the range of items with which the multiprocess is feed:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(working_queue, output_queue):
    while True:
        if working_queue.empty() is True:
            break #this is supposed to end the process.
        else:
            picked = working_queue.get()
            if picked % 2 == 0: 
                output_queue.put(picked)
            else:
                working_queue.put(picked+1)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    static_input = xrange(100)    
    working_q = mp.Queue()
    output_q = mp.Queue()
    for i in static_input:
        working_q.put(i)
    processes = [mp.Process(target=worker,args=(working_q, output_q)) for i in range(mp.cpu_count())]
    for proc in processes:
        proc.start()
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
    results_bank = []
    while True:
        if output_q.empty() is True:
            break
        else:
            results_bank.append(output_q.get())
    print len(results_bank) # length of this list should be equal to static_input, which is the range used to populate the input queue. In other words, this tells whether all the items placed for processing were actually processed.
    results_bank.sort()
    print results_bank
```

Has anyone any idea about how to make this code to run properly?

Comment: By the way, I would highly appreciate if you could help me to realise what make a multiprocessing python code not sensible to OS platforms. The code above behaves differently if run in Windows 7 or MacOS; in the former the console get unresponsive while in the latter the items in the results are repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will never stop:

Each worker gets an item from the queue as long as it is not empty:

```
picked = working_queue.get()
```

and puts a new one for each that it got:

```
working_queue.put(picked+1)
```

As a result the queue will never be empty except when the timing between the process happens to be such that the queue is empty at the moment one of the processes calls `empty()`. Because the queue length is initially `100` and you have as many processes as `cpu_count()` I would be surprised if this ever stops on any realistic system.

Well executing the code with slight modification proves me wrong, it does stop at some point, which actually surprises me. Executing the code with one process there seems to be a bug, because after some time the process freezes but does not return. With multiple processes the result is varying.

Adding a short sleep period in the loop iteration makes the code behave as I expected and explained above. There seems to be some timing issue between `Queue.put`, `Queue.get` and `Queue.empty`, although they are supposed to be thread-safe. Removing the `empty` test also gives the expected result (without ever getting stuck at an empty queue).

Found the reason for the varying behaviour. The objects put on the queue are not flushed immediately. Therefore `empty` might return `False` although there are items in the queue waiting to be flushed.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues):

> **Note**: When an object is put on a queue, the object is pickled and a
>   background thread later flushes the pickled data to an underlying
>   pipe. This has some consequences which are a little surprising, but
>   should not cause any practical difficulties – if they really bother
>   you then you can instead use a queue created with a manager.
>
> 1. After putting an object on an empty queue there may be an infinitesimal delay before the queue’s empty() method returns False and get_nowait() can return without raising Queue.Empty.
> 2. If multiple processes are enqueuing objects, it is possible for the objects to be received at the other end out-of-order. However, objects enqueued by the same process will always be in the expected order with respect to each other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I included the missing else in both empty-tests, but it did not worked. I tried to remove the empty-test, but the process is still getting stuck. I used the empty-test to ensure the processes end at some point. Otherwise, processes get stuck when asking an empty queue for data. I thought the unreliability of the .emtpy() method  was only a concern for the last rounds of processes, when there are few items in the queue, and CPUs 'mistakenly' read a queue as empty while other CPU is just queuing some more items. In that case a single CPU should be able to finish the work.

Comment: Could the use of a .lock over a global variable, whose length is compared with the amount of original queued data, be the solution to end processes before they get stuck with empty queues?

Comment: @Yag A simple fix would be to add a small timeout to `get()`, such that an exception is thrown when the queue does not deliver anymore items instead of checking `empty`. Of course there doesn't seem to be a guarantee for this to work all the time either. Otherwise I guess you need to use a shared state. There are probably better solutions though that I am unaware of.

Comment: thanks for your comments. The timeout plus the exception are indeed useful. Because of the parallel design, maintaining the empty test can be convenient as a timeout exception could be the result of temporary empty queue which is just being repopulated. I tried to solve this [with a manager, but a normal queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680903/using-a-a-manager-for-updating-a-queue-in-a-python-multiprocess) finally worked for me.