# Using a a manager for updating a Queue in a Python multiprocess

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I am designing a Python multiprocessing code to work in a queue that might be updated along the processing. The following code sometimes works, or get stuck, or rises an Empty error.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(working_queue, output_queue):
    while True:
        if working_queue.empty() is True:
            break    
        else:
            picked = working_queue.get_nowait()
            if picked % 2 == 0: 
                    output_queue.put(picked)
            else:
                working_queue.put(picked+1)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    static_input = xrange(100)    
    working_q = manager.Queue()
    output_q = mp.Queue()
    for i in static_input:
        working_q.put(i)
    processes = [mp.Process(target=worker,args=(working_q, output_q)) for i in range(mp.cpu_count())]
    for proc in processes:
        proc.start()
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
    results_bank = []
    while True:
       if output_q.empty() is True:
           break
       results_bank.append(output_q.get_nowait())
    print len(results_bank) # length of this list should be equal to static_input, which is the range used to populate the input queue. In other words, this tells whether all the items placed for processing were actually processed.
    results_bank.sort()
    print results_bank
```

Should I use a list as a global variable, and lock it, instead of a manager.Queue()?

Comment: This code works just fine on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Could you try it some more times? For me it worked well around three times out of ten.

Comment: The problem is in `if working_queue.empty() is True:` one process could check if is empty the queue just before another process pops the last value and then the call to `working_queue.get_nowait()` will raise the exception

Comment: I thought the `manager.Queue` could ensure that its `.empty()` status the incoming worker reads is the actual one. I might be wrong thought. If this is the case could you help me to clarify the problem?  On the other hand, I will check if the `_nowait` is really necessary.

Comment: I just used a simple .get_nowait(). Actually the whole process gets stuck if this method is not used. I think that, even thought a manager has been set, there might be workers that keep waiting for an item to be provided by an empty queue. This means that the manager.Queue could not be required. I will try to remove it and will comment on this.

Comment: I just tried the same code without the usage of a manager and including the exception. It seems to run just fine. I will make the correspondent adjustments to the answer I posted below. Thanks!

Comment: @xndrme could you have a look in the code posted in the answer below? It worked well when the initial amount of items to be processed (static_input) is in the order of 1000. But when I try with an scale of 10000 items, the process gets stuck. What do you think it is happening?

Comment: In my personal experience (and also what I was taught) when you access shared data between process you should use a synchronization primitive cause really weird things could happen and you almost never will be able to reproduce it by debugging, so I recommend you to use a lock, I will drop you an answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a `try:` and `except Exception:` to handle the Empty error. The results seem to be consistent now. Please let me know If you find problems I overlooked in this solution.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(working_queue, output_queue):
    while True:
        try:
            if working_queue.empty() is True:
                break  
            else:
                picked = working_queue.get_nowait()
                if picked % 2 == 0: 
                        output_queue.put(picked)
                else:
                    working_queue.put(picked+1)
        except Exception:
            continue

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Manager seem to be unnecessary.
    #manager = mp.Manager()
    #working_q = manager.Queue()

    working_q = mp.Queue()
    output_q = mp.Queue()
    static_input = xrange(100)     
    for i in static_input:
        working_q.put(i)
    processes = [mp.Process(target=worker,args=(working_q, output_q)) for i in range(mp.cpu_count())]
    for proc in processes:
        proc.start()
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
    results_bank = []
    while True:
       if output_q.empty() is True:
           break
       results_bank.append(output_q.get_nowait())
    print len(results_bank) # length of this list should be equal to static_input, which is the range used to populate the input queue. In other words, this tells whether all the items placed for processing were actually processed.
    results_bank.sort()
    print results_bank
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a lock to protect the access to shared data, it's safer (and will protect you from weird behavior of the process):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(working_queue, output_queue, lock):
    while True:
        shouldBeak = False
        lock.acquire()
        if working_queue.empty() is True:
            shouldBeak = True    
        else:

            picked = working_queue.get_nowait()
            if picked % 2 == 0: 
                output_queue.put(picked)
            else:
                working_queue.put(picked+1)
        lock.release()
        if shouldBeak:
            break
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    static_input = xrange(1000)    
    working_q = manager.Queue()
    output_q = mp.Queue()
    lock = mp.Lock()
    for i in static_input:
        working_q.put(i)
    processes = [mp.Process(target=worker,args=(working_q, output_q,lock)) for i in range(mp.cpu_count())]
    for proc in processes:
        proc.start()
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
    results_bank = []
    while True:
       if output_q.empty() is True:
           break
       results_bank.append(output_q.get_nowait())
    print len(results_bank) # length of this list should be equal to static_input, which is the range used to populate the input queue. In other words, this tells whether all the items placed for processing were actually processed.
    results_bank.sort()
    print results_bank
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I just tried out your proposal with an input range of 1000 and 10000 items. The program works well with the former, but it gets stuck with the latter.